# Killing a random directed link in both direction in netlogo

Tags: network-programming, netlogo

Greeting,

I am very new to netlogo, and is very interested in GIS and network feature in netlogo.

Currently, I have constructed a directed graph network.
I would like to implement a function to kill a directed link path in both direction.

I have found way to kill a link in both direction if you know which are the linkage of the 2 node to kill off. Below is the code for that (by Seth Tisue in one of the question thread) :

```
ask a [ ask link-with b [ die ] ]
```

I would like to kill of a random linkage in both direction. I assume I would need to use "ask one-of links [ die ]" and another part of the code to kill of the corresponding other direction of the linkage.

**I guess my question would be how the mechanism of "one-of" work so that I would be able to store this random link first, and then kill off both direction using the first code above.**

As a side line, I am also puzzled by how netlogo work with variable which is quite unlike normal C++ program(my fundamental is with c++ coding). I do quite a lot of importing for my network and GIS shapefile, and currently I am still not using netlogo engine as my computational engine(a waste for me).

**How do you store a simple "x=1+1" into a global variable in netlogo?**
Really sorry if this question is too simple for most.

Comment: to read about variables in NetLogo, see http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#variables

Answer (score 2):

Just as a general stackoverflow convention, if you have two questions, please ask them as separate questions. This is to make stackoverflow a useful resource for programmers, so that the title and question and answer are both together and easily found.

1. First, how do you even know there is a link in both directions? Typically directed graphs have many pairs of nodes where there is A to B or B to A but not both. The code below tests the other direction and kills both.
2. I have included your example of setting variable x to the value of 1 + 1 in the setup.

I am convinced there is a better way of doing this as NetLogo code is usually less ugly, but I can't find it. The following code is a complete runnable example that creates a bunch of nodes and links and then kills a link (including the reciprocal if it exists) whenever the kill-link procedure is run.

```
globals [x tonode fromnode]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  repeat 100
  [ ask one-of turtles
    [ create-link-to one-of other turtles  ; will not be created if already link
    ]
  ]

  set x 1 + 1
end

to kill-link
  ask one-of links
  [ set fromnode end1
    set tonode end2
    die
  ]
  ask tonode
  [ if out-link-neighbor? fromnode
    [ ask out-link-to fromnode [die]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: How about `to kill-link  let dead1 one-of links  let dead2 [[out-link-to other-end] of end2] of dead1  ask (link-set dead1 dead2) [ die ]  end`

Comment: Thanks to both JenB and Seth Tisue! I am quite new to stackoverflow and I will abide to single question to per thread in the future. As for the "kills a link (including the reciprocal if it exists)" way, personally, i think JenB version is more readable while Seth Tisue version is the shorter version possible. Nevertheless, both of the method works! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Global variable should be declared at the beginning of program:

```
globals [
   my-global-link; this will be my global variable 
   my-another-one-link; another one 
]
```

To "store" random link use it like:

```
to do-something
   set my-global-link one-of links
end
```

For local variables (inside a procedure) just use let do declare it first:

```
to do-something
   let tmp-global-link one-of links
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, though this isn't what I wanted, But nevertheless, I thanks you for your time in trying to help!